# Print all metatable content

Tags: lua, metatable, meta-method

I have table:

```
[кнк] = (table) 
[20-6-2014] = (table) 
  [16] = Steve,Maria 
[16-6-2014] = (table) 
  [17] = Elice, Hans
  [18] = Steve, Maria, Hans
```

And i have dirty but working code:

```
function af.info(farm_name,date,time,name_string)
    r=os.date("*t")
    today = date..'-'..r.month..'-'..r.year
    real_date = today
    if farm == nil then
        send_msg(name_string,"Error. No database.")
    else
      if af.contains(farm,farm_name) then
  print("First Stage - Search for farm")
    if af.contains(farm[farm_name],real_date) then
      if af.contains(farm[farm_name][real_date],time) then
        print(name_string,"Вы запросили данные о ферме "..farm_name.."\nНа данный момент запись на "..date.." число, "..time.." часов, состоит из:\n"..table.concat(farm[farm_name][real_date][time],", ",1,#farm[farm_name][real_date][time]))
    send_msg(name_string,"Вы запросили данные о ферме "..farm_name.."\nНа данный момент запись на "..date.." число, "..time.." часов, состоит из:\n"..table.concat(farm[farm_name][real_date][time],", ",1,#farm[farm_name][real_date][time]))
    else
      print(name_string,"Вы запросили данные о ферме "..farm_name.."\nНа данный момент запись на "..date.." число состоит из:\n"..table.concat(farm[farm_name][real_date],", ",1,#farm[farm_name][real_date]))
      send_msg(name_string,"Вы запросили данные о ферме "..farm_name.."\nНа данный момент запись на "..date.." число состоит из:\n"..table.concat(farm[farm_name][real_date],", ",1,#farm[farm_name][real_date]))
        end
    end
end

end
return error_msg, farm_message
end
```

Its telegram bot. When it's asked about farm by name, date and time - it's work ok.

My trouble is near else statement. I want ask bot about farm and date. It should return list like "At 16-6-2014, at farm "knk" will be 2 farms. At 17 - 2 agents. At 18 - 3 agents"

Simple table.concat didn't work for me.

Comment: Could you translate the literals to english? It's really hard to tell what they are supposed to print/do.

Comment: If your search criteria don't match you want to print out a summary of the possible information instead? `table.concat` only works on "arrays", that is tables with consecutive integers from 1..n. You will need to walk (and sort) your entries yourself (using pairs).

Comment: Thanks, Etan. Your answer show me right way to code.